# Can't figure out how to pass copies to DYMO.Label.Framework.3.0.js SDK

Tags: javascript, php, sdk

I have been searching the internet for three weeks and have been waiting 10 days for Dymo engineering to answer my question about setting the number of copies that are to be printed.

Here is my post:
http://developers.dymo.com/2018/05/29/updated-js-sdk-and-dls/#comment-85589

I received one reply from the engineering staff and was told to go to this page.
http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkJavaScriptHelp/symbols/dymo.label.framework.ILabel.html#print

All of my questions were to be answered by this page. HA!

On the page, there is this entry.
{string} printParamsXml
The print parameters, such as the number of copies, print quality, etc. See PrintParams.xsd. http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/PrintParams.xsd

To me, this is just an XML page. It does not tell me how to pass the information needed to

```
w("dymo.label.framework.createTapePrintParamsXml",function(a){if(!a)return"";var b=R("<TapePrintParams/>"),d=b.documentElement;a.copies&&S(d,"Copies",a.copies.toString());a.jobTitle&&S(d,"JobTitle",a.jobTitle);a.flowDirection&&S(d,"FlowDirection",a.flowDirection);a.alignment&&S(d,"Alignment",a.alignment);a.cutMode&&S(d,"CutMode",a.cutMode);return ie(b)});
```

Which is inside http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.3.0.js.

I am calling the function on line 402 of 
https://github.com/juggernautsei/dymo-print-logic/blob/juggernautsei-patch-3/PrintMeThatLabel.js

But when I print, there is only one label printed. I have to back up and let you know what else I found.

http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkJavaScriptHelp/symbols/dymo.label.framework.html#.printLabel

dymo.label.framework.printLabel(printerName, printParamsXml, labelXml, labelSetXml)
Prints one or more labels.

I have set the code to this.

```
            var labelSet = new dymo.label.framework.LabelSetBuilder();
            var params = dymo.label.framework.createLabelWriterPrintParamsXml({Copies:copies});

            labelSet.addRecord().setText(objName, text);


            // print
            //label.print(printer.name, null, labelSet.toString());
            // print and get status
            var printJob = label.printAndPollStatus(printer.name, params.copies, labelSet.toString(), function(printJob, printJobStatus)
            {
```

I still on get one label. Seems like I have all the pieces of the puzzle but can't complete the picture. HELP...please.

Comment: Figured out the issue with the help of a friend. Change this ({Copies:copies}) to this ({copies:copies}) and this params.copies to this params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var params = dymo.label.framework.createLabelWriterPrintParamsXml({copies:2,twinTurboRoll:'Right',printQuality:'Text'});                
//now params contains <LabelWriterPrintParams><Copies>2</Copies><PrintQuality>Text</PrintQuality><TwinTurboRoll>Right</TwinTurboRoll></LabelWriterPrintParams>
var printJob = label.printAndPollStatus(printer.name, params, labelSet.toString(), function(printJob, printJobStatus)
{
    // output status
    var statusStr = 'Job Status: ' + printJobStatus.statusMessage;

    var result = (printJobStatus.status != dymo.label.framework.PrintJobStatus.ProcessingError 
    && printJobStatus.status != dymo.label.framework.PrintJobStatus.Finished);

    // reenable when the job is done (either success or fail)
    printButton.disabled = result;

    //if (!result)
    //    statusStr = '';

    setTextContent(jobStatusMessageSpan, statusStr);

    return result;

}, 1000);
```

It works very well with the DYMO labelWriter Wireless printer

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: The answer to the question about mass printing is that it works the same as any other mass printing. You are able to set the number of copies you would like to print. It is not a one and done. The client-side application that is installed is like a print driver of sorts. (My interpretation of what it is doing) The connection to the cloud allows permission to print as though it was coming from a local application.